# Can't start MySQL when bound to private ip

Tags: mysql

My vps is on Linode. For example's sake, let's say my public IP is x.x.x.x and my private IP is y.y.y.y/Z. In my.cnf, if I set

```
bind-address = x.x.x.x
```

and restart MySQL, everything is fine and works just fine. However, if I do

```
bind-address = y.y.y.y
```

MySQL is unable to start back up at all. Is there some step I'm skipping?

Comment: You're skipping the part where you tell us what you found when you read the mysql error log to see why it won't start.  Does the address in question appear in the output of `ifconfig`?

Comment: Found the problem actually. I had thought Linode's autoconfig automatically sets up the interfaces file with the private ip, but apparently it doesn't.